# Why iterating with $_ takes longer

Tags: performance, perl, foreach

I was wondering based on many books on Internet, if $_ is really faster way of iterating through array (no instantiating of new variable), but somehow I always get different results. Here's the performance code test:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Time::HiRes qw(time);

use strict;
use warnings;

# $_ is a default argument for many operators, and also for some control structures.

my $test_array = [1..1000000];

my $number_of_tests = 100;
my $dollar_wins = 0;
my $dollar_wins_sum = 0;

for (my $i = 1; $i <= $number_of_tests; $i++) {
    my $odd_void_array = [];
    my $start_time_1 = time();
    foreach my $item (@{$test_array}) {
        if ($item % 2 == 1) {
            push (@{$odd_void_array}, $item);
        }
    }
    foreach my $item_odd (@{$odd_void_array}) {
    }
    my $end_time_1 = time();

    $odd_void_array = [];
    my $start_time_2 = time();
    foreach (@{$test_array}) {
        if ($_ % 2 == 1) {
            push (@{$odd_void_array}, $_);
        }
    }
    foreach (@{$odd_void_array}) {
    }
    my $end_time_2 = time();

    my $diff = ($end_time_1-$start_time_1) - ($end_time_2-$start_time_2);
    if ($diff > 0) {
        $dollar_wins ++;
        $dollar_wins_sum += $diff;
        print "Dollar won ($dollar_wins out of $i) with diff $diff \n";
    }
}

print "=================================\n";
print "When using dollar underscore, execution was faster in $dollar_wins cases (".(($dollar_wins/$number_of_tests)*100)."%), with average difference of ".($dollar_wins_sum/$dollar_wins)."\n";
```

So, I have twice iterating (once with assigning to my $item, other without). I get mostly that iterating with $_ was faster in about 20-30% cases.

Shouldn't be iterating without new variable be faster?

Comment: sa $_ je onda brze ili sporije?

Comment: It actually doesn't copy the value into a variable. Test this: perl -e '@a = (1, 2, 3); $_++ foreach (@a); print @a;' You will see that it updates @a. It actually aliases the variables in the list to the name you define. This may impact the performance.

Comment: Let me translate what @mpapec asked :)

"So, is it $_ faster or slower then?"

I say, based on my finding, $_ is slower...I'm just wondering how's that? :)

Comment: foreach variable is always aliased regardless of `$_` or some other variable usage.

Comment: it isn't somehow on the same line with `I get mostly that iterating with $_ was faster in about 20-30% cases` :)

Comment: and iterating without was faster in 70-80% cases :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You aren't really benchmarking iteration with different variables.

- Your timings includes array creation and other calculations.
- You only tell which is faster, not by how much.
- You have too few iterations to tell anything reliable.

Let's take this better test that actually benchmarks what you are claiming to benchmark:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark ':hireswallclock', 'cmpthese';

my @numbers = 1..100_000;

cmpthese -3, {
  '$_' => sub {
    for (@numbers) {
      1;
    }
  },
  'my $x' => sub {
    for my $x (@numbers) {
      1;
    }
  },
  '$x' => sub {
    my $x;
    for $x (@numbers) {
      1;
    }
  },
}
```

Result:

```
       Rate    $_ my $x    $x
$_    107/s    --   -0%   -0%
my $x 107/s    0%    --   -0%
$x    108/s    0%    0%    --
```

So they are equally fast on my test system (perl 5.18.2 built for i686-linux-thread-multi-64int).

My suspicion is that *using* `$_` is slightly slower than a lexical, as it's a global variable. However, the speed of iteration is equivalent. Indeed, modifying the benchmark…

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark ':hireswallclock', 'cmpthese';

my @numbers = 1..100_000;

cmpthese -3, {
  '$_' => sub {
    for (@numbers) {
      $_ % 2 == 0;
    }
  },
  'my $x' => sub {
    for my $x (@numbers) {
      $x % 2 == 0;
    }
  },
  '$x' => sub {
    my $x;
    for $x (@numbers) {
      $x % 2 == 0;
    }
  },
}
```

… gives

```
        Rate    $_    $x my $x
$_    40.3/s    --   -1%   -6%
$x    40.6/s    1%    --   -5%
my $x 42.9/s    7%    6%    --
```

but the effects are still too small to draw any solid conclusion.

Comment: lexicals should indeed perform marginally better than package variables, but I can't find any reference to such claim.

Comment: @mpapec Look at some simple snippets with `-MO=Concise`. Using a global is essentially a lookup in the stash (which is just a special hash mapping names to globs). Lexicals are looked up on the pad (which is essentially an array). This in itself makes lexicals faster, in addition to possible cache effects. But in practice, the difference is minute. Other aspects of lexicals are more important (mainly, their scoping benefits).

Comment: A stash is a [C struct](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/HEAD:/gv.h#l11), not a special hash. That's merely how it's accessed from Perl.

Comment: Lexicals are essentially in a 2D array (think recursion). (Not sure if "pad" refers to the whole thing, or just the second dimension.)

Comment: If you change the `@numbers` array to be `1..2` instead of `1..100_000`, the difference becomes more apparent; lexicals can be almost 10% faster.

Comment: @ikegami You've linked to the C struct used in the typeglob definition, which is not a stash (“symbol table hash”). The “Pad” mostly refers to the AV of SVs for the current recursion level, and each CV has an associated [“padlist”](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/HEAD:/pad.h#l31). In practice, “pad” is used in both meanings.